# How to get my array to sort properly? Recursive Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion

After many times to try to solve this issue, I can't seem to solve my dilemma. When trying to run my program, the unsorted array will not sort when printing "Sorted Array". Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

```
public class RecursiveSorter {

    private int[] sortedArray;
    private int[] array;

    public RecursiveSorter() {
        array = new int[1];
    }

public RecursiveSorter(int[] a) {
    array = a;
}

public void setArray(int[] a) {
    array = a;
}

public int[] getSortedArray() {
    return sortedArray;
}

public int[] getOriginalArray() {
    return array;
}

public int[] sort() {
    sortedArray = array;
    recursiveSort(sortedArray.length - 1);
    return sortedArray;
}

public int[] recursiveSort(int endIndex) {
    if (endIndex > 0) {
        int m = getMaxIndex(endIndex, sortedArray);
        swap(m, endIndex, sortedArray);
        recursiveSort(endIndex-1);
    }
    return sortedArray;
}

public int getMaxIndex(int endIndex, int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
        if (a[i] < max) {
            max = a[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
//Changed it to make sure that it is swapping the elements correctly
public void swap(int src, int dest, int[] a) {
    if(dest <= src)
    {
    int temp = a[dest];
    a[dest] = a[src];
    a[src] = temp;

     dest++;
     src++;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "Original: " + prettyPrint(getOriginalArray()) + "\n" +
           "Sorted:   " + prettyPrint(getSortedArray());
}

private String prettyPrint(int[] a) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i : a)
        s += i + " ";
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Automate running, but not testing
    int[] array = {5, 67, 12, 20};
    RecursiveSorter s = new RecursiveSorter(array);
    s.sort();
    System.out.println(s); // uses Sorter.toString
}

}
```

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. First of all: `sortedArray = array`: keep in mind, that an array is an object. With this statement, you do not copy the array, but `array` and `sortedArray` reference to the same memory adress. Look into at [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). Can you explain your sort algorithm? This makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problems. 2 are in `getMaxIndex()`: you were not including the last element in the test for the max, and the test for max is not the right. You are computing the *min*.

```
public int getMaxIndex(int endIndex, int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= endIndex; i++) {   // use <= instead of <
        if (a[i] > max) {                   // change < in >
            max = a[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

And one problem in `swap()`

```
public void swap(int src, int dest, int[] a) {
    if(src <= dest)      // reverse src and dest
    {
        int temp = a[dest];
        a[dest] = a[src];
        a[src] = temp;

        dest++; // no use, dest is local
        src++; // idem
    }
}
```

Then you will have:

Original: 5 12 20 67 
Sorted:   5 12 20 67

Actually the orginal array is modified because `array` and `sortedArray` reference the **same** array of `int`. There is no copy in Java. When you do

```
public int[] sort() {
    sortedArray = array;
    recursiveSort(sortedArray.length - 1);
    return sortedArray;
}
```

`sortedArray` *points* to the same `int[]` as `array`. If you want to keep the orginal one, you need to explicitly do a copy, for instance with `System.arrayCopy(...)`.

Comment: @OMG Thank you so much! :D I didn't realize that I did some of that stuff reversed. Once again, thank you! You saved me so much time and aggravation.

Answer (score 1):

I traced the problem down to two points:

first, you have an unnecessary `if` in `swap(...)`:

```
public void swap(int src, int dest, int[] a)
{
    // if(dest <= src)
    // {
        int temp = a[dest];
        a[dest] = a[src];
        a[src] = temp;

    //     dest++;
    //     src++;
    // }
}
```

Second, you have a little bug in the `for` loop of `getMaxIndex(...)`:

```
public int getMaxIndex(int endIndex, int[] a)
{
    int max = a[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= endIndex; i++) // substituted < with <=
    {
        if (a[i] < max)
        {
            max = a[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

With these changes (and mentionded [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)), the algorithm should work as intended.

Comment: Thank you :) I really do achieve you helping me by the way. However, according to my assignment, my professor wanted me to use an if statement for some odd reason. I did use your advice when pointing out that endIndex needed to changed to <= . My program is running fine now :D thanks dude.

Answer (score -2):

Why you are not sing

```
// sorting array in #java.util.Arrays;
Arrays.sort(array);
```

And dont need to recusive call and all

If you need to write your own code, then Choose any sorting algorthim, implement that one by your own.

```
private static void sort(int[] array){
 boolean swapped = true;
int j = 0;
int tmp;
while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = tmp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}